# block.basefee, tx.gasprice and gasleft() in Optimism/Arbitrum

Tags: gas, gas-price, fees

Does `block.basefee`, `tx.gasprice` and `gasleft()` work the same in Optimism and Arbitrum as they do on L1? If not, how do they differ? Do these L2s even have a base fee like L1 does?

I'm trying to make a function that reimburses `msg.sender` for gas fees paid, but I'm wondering how an approach to doing this might differ between L1 and various L2s.

Answer (score 0):

did you find any answers to this?

Does block.basefee, tx.gasprice and gasleft() work the same in Optimism and Arbitrum as they do on L1?

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer, but no I went down another path